# About Global Temporary Table and Stored Procedure in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am confusing with the global temporary table in Oracle:

For example, I want to write a SP MySP which can be used by 5 users at the same time.

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE temp 
     (ID NUMBER, COL1 VARCHAR2(4000), COL2 VARCHAR2(4000));

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MySP
(
  id NUMBER
, input1 varchar2(4000)
, input2 varchar2(4000)
)
AUTHID CURRENT_USER IS

sql_stmt VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
   sql_stmt := 'INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('
             + TOCHAR(ID,99) + ','
             + input1 + ','
             + input2
             + ')';
   execute sql_stmt;

END MySP;
```

My question is:
  When the five user run the SP at same time, will they  not interrupt with each other because they use the same global temp table?

Comment: Do you mean 5 different users? Or the same user at 5 sessions?

Comment: Why do you convert a number into a CHAR and then insert into a number column?

Answer (score 1):

> GLOBAL TEMPORARY
>
> Specify GLOBAL TEMPORARY to indicate that the table is temporary and
>   that its definition is visible to all sessions with appropriate
>   privileges. **The data in a temporary table is visible only to the
>   session that inserts the data into the table.**

http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF01402

Comment: Thanks Doe.  So this means everyone can use the table at the same time?  Can 2 users create the global temporary table with the same table name?

Comment: You have to create the table once, then the table is visible to **all** sessions with the **appropriate privileges**.